# what's the voltage across F

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

Given: Va= 10V, Vc= 15V Ve= 20V find Vb and Vf
so I calculated the voltages using KVL and I got Vb= 10V and Vf= 25V but when I checked my answers it showed that Vf was 5V
is Vf = 5V if so then why? 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQXF1.png]

Comment: Are the signs of all the given voltages exactly as written in the question?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I'm getting.
Maybe it's a typo ?

> **Loop 1:**
>
> -Ve + Va + Vb = 0;
>
> **Isolate Vb**
>
> Vb = Ve – Va;
>
> 20-10 = 10 => Vb = 10;
>
> **Loop 2:**
>
> -Vb – Vc – Vd = 0;
>
> **Isolate Vd**
>
> -Vd = Vb + Vc;
>
> 10+15 = -25;
>
> Vf + Vd = 0
>
> Vf = -Vd => Vf = 25;

Comment: Please don't give out solutions to homework problems. We prefer to give hints that guide the OP toward answering their own question.

Comment: I chose to give him a full solution to prove to him that his facit list is indeed wrong.